# React Native and WMS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, wms

I am developing a mobile application in React Native requiring the use of Web Map Services. I have not found any library or framework that allows use WMS and react native at same time. In React (Web) I found [one](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet). 
My question is:

Do you know if exists any library or framework that allows me to work with WMS and React Native, or if there is any possibility of integrating a library of React (web) in React native?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The approach I decided to use is the following:

1. Using `WebView` from [react-native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html).
2. Using [openlayers](http://openlayers.org/).

Declare a variable in render method from your react-native class which contains the HTML code from a Map of openlayers:

`` render() {
    var html = `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Simple Map</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
        <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
        <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
        <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.0/build/ol.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="map" class="map"></div>
        <script>
          var map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [
              new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
              })
            ],
            target: 'map',
            view: new ol.View({
              center: [0, 0],
              zoom: 2
            })
          });
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
    ` ``

Then pass this variable to the WebView:

`return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <WebView
          ref={webview => { this.webview = webview; }}
          source={{html}}
          onMessage={this.onMessage}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}`

If you want to communicate the react-native side with WebView side, take a look to the WebView example from react-native.

You can find more examples in the openlayers example page.

Comment: Not able to import openlayers in react-native. I tried importing as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45397161/import-ol-from-openlayers-in-react-native?answertab=votes#tab-top 
But shows error as Unable to resolve "!!../node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./autocomplete.css" from "node_modules/react-openlayers/dist/react-openlayers.umd.js"

Comment: More modern WMS solution for this would be use [react-native-maps][1], since it's broadly supported with nice documentation.


  [1]: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps